# why is my program stuck on a thread?

Tags: python, multithreading

so  Im writing a program that using threads but when I make a new thread, it gets caught up stuck in that thread and the rest of the program doesn't run.

```
t=threading.Thread(target=get_connections())
t.start()

def get_connections(self):
    c, addr=self.s.accept()
```

Why is my program stuck on this thread?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the function as you pass it to `Thread`.  Don't include the parentheses.  Change it to this:

```
t=threading.Thread(target=get_connections)
```

A second problem is that you are referencing `get_connections()` before it is defined.  You'll need to move that definition up a bit.

Comment: oh my bad... i should have realized i had those parentheses... haha thanks!.  and yea i know the method is after the call.  I was just pasting parts of the code here and put that out of order.

Answer (score 0):

1. `target=get_connections()` will pass the return value by get_connections as target parameter.
2. According to the definition of get_connections, it seems like a method of a class.
   Using get_connections as your code to create thread t, the instance of class is None.